# MySQL Force Fail a statement when querying with an invalid (non existent) foreign key value

Tags: mysql

What I am looking for is a way to have a MySQL statement fail when querying table through an invalid index (id) of a foreign key column of that table.

## DETAILS:

I have two tales:

cars:

```
id | username | brand | model | location
```

reservations:

```
id | car_id | username | date
```

The column `reservations.car_id` is bound to the column `cars.id` via a foreign key (ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE), where the column `reservations.car_id` is the child of the column `cars.id`

## Wanted Behaviour

**What I am trying to do is to have a SQL statement fail when trying to fetch a single or multiple reservation rows using an invalid `car_id`.** The statement should return an empty array when the car_id is valid *(a row with that id is present in the cars table)*, but there are no reservations in the table with that car_id.

I am looking for this behavior as I want to distinguish when a query is successful but simply has no results (so an empty array), and when a query fails (so I would return None). For the sake of my project, when querying reservations via an invalid car_id, I want this to fail and not simply return an empty array.

## Actual Behaviour

When I run the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE car_id = :car_id
```

This statement is successful, but when fetching the query results, it simply returns an empty array. I would want this to return null instead.

## These are the attempts I have tried before:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
            JOIN cars ON reservations.car_id = cars.id
            WHERE cars.id = :car_id;
```

This statement is successful but returns an empty array.

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE car_id = ( SELECT id FROM cars WHERE id = :car_id );
```

This statement is also successful but returns an empty array.

Comment: I think select from `cars` and use a `left join` for `reservations`. If `reservations.id` is null then there is no reservation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by *fail*. If you mean *[raise an exception](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) and get the calling program to handle it*, you'll need a stored procedure or similar code. But this would be a strange and hard-to-maintain way to fulfill your requirement.

If you mean return the value `None` somewhere in the result set, you can do something like this. It uses the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern for detecting missing joined rows.

```sql
SELECT cars.id, 
       COALESCE(reservations.car_id, 'No reservations!!!') 
  FROM cars
  LEFT JOIN reservations  ON reservations.car_id = cars.id
 WHERE cars.id = :car_id;
```

I'd try to put this into a more useful query, but you did `SELECT *` so I can't guess at the columns your tables have.